# How to convert .pickle or .dat file into .tflite using python?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning, computer-vision, tensorflow-lite

I have .pickle file , Which is consisting of arrays of encodings of face, now I want to convert it into .tflite extension file. How can I do it?
Thanks in advance! Answer would be appreciated

Comment: You can convert only Keras models, frozen graphs of TensorFlow to .tflite. Face encodings do not constitute a model.

Comment: @shubhampanchal how can I run .pickle file into tflite in andriod, do you have any other approach to handle this situation?

Comment: Which object does the .pkl file contain?

Comment: face encoding and attribute values contained in .pkl file